# How to install JNativeHook Library?

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries, jnativehook

I am trying to use the JNativeHook library to provide global keyboard and mouse listeners for my Java application. I downloaded the source files from [here](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) but I am not sure how to install it to eclipse and make a use of it. I have also looked at the [Compiling Instructions](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Compiling). I followed all the steps, but it seems to be confusing for me.

Can anyone guide me on how to use the JNativeHook Library? I am using Eclipse as IDE and windows 7 as an operating system.

Answer (score 11):

Follow below steps to install JNativeHook in Eclipse:

1. Goto [release](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases), download and unzip JNativeHook-2.0.0.zip, then get the **JNativeHook.jar** in the `JNativeHook/jar` folder.
2. In Eclipse, `Right click on project > properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs`
3. Finally, add **JNativeHook.jar**

If you want to install with maven locally you can also proceed with [these instruction](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues/5).

Answer (score 0):

[`maven` dependencies are provided](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.1stleg/jnativehook) so just add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```