# Java: how to log keystrokes in the background?

Tags: java, background, jframe, counter, daemon

So I am currently writing a program that counts specific keys that I am pressing. The counting works fine, though I want the program to completely run in the background (without an open window or a sign in the taskbar).

So is there a way in Java to completely run a process in the background? I'm currently using a `JFrame` for the counting.

Comment: Basically, you want a keylogger.. Right??

Comment: Yea but for counting :)... Like the number of times I'm pressing tab or ctrl

Answer (score 3):

You could use JNativeHook here is an example that prints every key and the number of keys pressed, you could modify this to your needs :-

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class Main implements NativeKeyListener
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    try
    {
      GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new Main());
  }

  private int count;
  @Override
  public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e)
  {
      System.out.println("Pressed "  + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
      count++;
      System.out.println(count);
  }

  @Override
  public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e)
  {

  }

  @Override
  public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e)
  {

  }
}
```

If you do not know how to import the JNativeHook library then [How to install JNativeHook Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393628/how-to-install-jnativehook-library)